# Crystal Report: how to detect if two section are on same page?

Tags: layout, crystal-reports

i have reporting layout problem in Crystal Report.  the user have required that the two sections be in one page, and those two sections should have enough space in between them.  so i put a new section in between them, around half inch.  the problem is when the first section occupied the whole space of first page, then the second section will have that in-between section(the one that facilitates the half inch spacing) before it.  they don't want the *extra* space on top of second page

my idea is to create a suppress formula for that in-between section:

pagenumber(first_section) <> pagenumber(second_section)

is there a function which could aid this conditional suppression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put a formula field in the section header containing something like:

```
shared numbervar sectionOnePageNum := PageNumber;
```

Then, make a suppress formula for the blank section like:

```
shared numbervar sectionOnePageNum;
PageNumber <> sectionOnePageNum;
```

That might work.

Comment: +1 i agree a shared variable is your best option. You might need a `WhilePrintingRecords` in the suppress formula.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in SAP CR. I was expecting Formula Fields to only work in the section they're added in. But now it seems that, even when they're not in the report itself, they will compute anyway. I tried to put the suppress formula on the header so it will be suppressed when it is in the same page as a certain section, where I added the formula field. 
That ended suppressing the header everywhere in the report.